# Ajax com dataType json retorna valor duplicado

Tags: ajax, json

Código em JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formUpdate').validate({
        submitHandler: function( form ){
            var dados = $( form ).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/pagina_consulta",
                data: dados,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true
            }).done(function(data) {
                showAlert(data.type, data.title, data.msg, data.pos);   
            }).fail(function(data) {
                showInternalErrorAlert();
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Retorno:

```
{"title":"Sucesso!","msg":"atualizado."}{"title":"Sucesso!","msg":"atualizado."}
```

Já simplifiquei o código e nada, **o console mostra o conteúdo dentro de {} em duplicidade**, como na linha acima. Só deveria retornar 1 title e 1 msg.
Já adianto que não é a página (url) que está retornando a duplicação, pois conferi tudo e até coloquei um retorno simples pra testar.
Como isso é possível?
Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui descobrir! Era duplicação nas rotas do MVC:

```
['namespace'  => 'app', 'route' => '/epi/solicitacao/upload-arquivo-item', 'controller' => 'epi-solicitacao', 'action' => 'upload-itemfile'],
['namespace'  => 'app', 'route' => '/epi/solicitacao/upload-arquivo-item', 'controller' => 'epi-solicitacao', 'action' => 'upload-itemfile'],
```